# AVRO Schema change lead to 409 conflict error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, avro

The setting looks like the following. We use kafka, zookeeper, kafdrop, and a schema-registry and also an avro-schema to automaticaly generate our objects. Now if we change an avro-schema e.g. add a new field and compile again our application it leeds into a 409 conflict error.

Is there a comman way that the system automaticaly register an updatet avro schema and also a new version of that avro-object and automaticaly use the newer avro-object version?